# rosdep error - conflicting rosdep definitions

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try to [install rosserial](http://answers.ros.org/question/2554/rosserial-installation) into BeagleBoard

```
ubuntu@omap:~$ rosdep install rosserial_arduino
ERROR: QUITTING: due to conflicting rosdep definitions, please resolve this conf
lict.
Rules for python-sip4 do not match:
        python-sip4-dev sip4 [/home/ubuntu/ros/common_rosdeps/rosdep.yaml]
        python-sip-dev [/home/ubuntu/ros/geometry/rosdep.yaml]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11603/rosdep-error---conflicting-rosdep-definitions/) by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 471 on 2011-10-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-20**:
ROS electric installed from source - ROS-Base: (Bare Bones) ROS package

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-10-20**:
What version of ROS is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect you are mixing the Electric `common_rosdeps` with the Diamondback `geometry` stack.

It is fine to have both installed on your machine, but stick to one distribution at a time in your `$ROS_ROOT` and `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-20**:
Thanks a lot! you was right!

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-10-20**:
try "roslocate info XXX --distro=electric" to make sure that you are pulling in the desired version. Or, just follow the ROS installation instructions for "ROS Desktop" which already provide you all of the same libraries in a coherent version.

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-20**:
and i havent any over ROS on board.

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-20**:
yes - but i  install it via roslocate info XXX and rosinstall XXX - could it be from over branch? O_o

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-10-20**:
ROS Base does not come with geometry or common_rosdeps, so I think joq's advice is correct.  Whereever those came from, they came from incompatible branches.

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-20**:
ROS electric installed from source - ROS-Base: (Bare Bones) ROS package